# Get date from php to javascript

Tags: php, time

I am trying to get dates from PHP (I receive them from a database in the format 2014-09-16 22:00:00).

I then create an object in PHP because I have to work on those date in some occasions and I use:

```
$output[$i]['when'] = new DateTime($output[$i]['when'], new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
```

Then I send that back in the javascript code with the following PHP command:

```
$line['when']->format('U')*1000
```

In fact, this line is in a foreach meaning that is the reason why you don't see a [$i].

My problem is that when going into javascript, it shows as 2 hours before. I am in CET and as I understand the format('U') means UTC. But I thought with specifying the datetimezone, this would work. How can I solve this? I know there is a 2 hours difference between CET and UTC so should I had that in milliseconds then * 1000 to have the microseconds?

EDIT: The 2 hours difference is only for some months, then it becomes 1 hour difference. I have then no idea how to solve this.

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a standard format that includes the timezone.  The primary two you should use for the most straightforward javascript compatibility are [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) or [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  For this, let's use RFC 2822.

So what you pass to your javascript should be the string returned from:

```
$line['when']->format(\DateTime::RFC2822);
```

There are constants on the [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for various standard formats.

Then in your javascript, you can do the following:

```
var myDate = new Date('Tue, 16 Sep 2014 20:39:32 +0100');
```

Which uses the RFC 2822 standard to [parse the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) into a new Date object, which you can then use as you would any other date object which should be in the correct timezone.